# Cloned repo, selected wrong checkout branch, how do I undo this?

Tags: git, repository, branch, atlassian-sourcetree

When cloning a repo in Sourcetree, I selected develop instead of master under the advanced options.

I haven't made any commits.

Now, I only see the develop branch and cannot use git flow to create a new feature branch until I have the master.

Can I remove the repo without losing and changes and just clone again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used source tree, but if you somehow cloned the repo with develop branch and you are missing master, do a simple checkout of master using following command. This pulls master branch and checkout master branch in your local repo.

```
git checkout master
```

I guess after this you can initialize git flow and put in the respective branch names during configuration.

Comment: Thanks, I was way overthinking this one. I guess I lack understanding of what exactly checkout does, so I'll have to do some review

Comment: @Adam Yea just get the basics clear on git like checkout, merge and branches etc and rest of it you can gradually pickup.